# Gerar um PDF de um Gráfico Morris

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, canvas, svg

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que gera um relatório usando os gráficos Morris (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/)

Os gráficos estão funcionando corretamente, agora preciso gerar um PDF desse gráfico. No entanto, me deparei que para fazer isso, quando o gráfico é SVG é diferente.

O arquivo PDF é gerado, mas sem o gráfico(sem as barras), apenas com as legendas.

Segue:

Index.cshtml contendo a div do gráfico

```
 <div class="panel-body" id="gerapdf">
     <div class="row">
         <b><span id="RelatorioItemContrato"></span></b>
         <br />
         <b><span id="RelatorioMes"></span></b>
         <br />
         <b><span id="RelatorioAno"></span></b>
         <br />
         <b><span id="RelatorioAtivo"></span></b>
     </div>
     <div id="RelatorioDesempenhoDataBarChart"></div> <!--Gráfico-->
     <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-heading">
                 Legenda
             </div>
             <div class="panel-body" id="legenda-fixa">

             </div>
             @*<div class="panel-footer">
             </div>*@
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

.JS

```
 var cache_width = $("#gerapdf").width(); //Criado um cache do CSS
 var a4 = [595.28, 841.89]; // Widht e Height de uma folha a4

 function getPDF() {
     // Setar o width da div no formato a4
     $("#gerapdf").width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');

     // Aqui ele cria a imagem e cria o pdf
     html2canvas($("#gerapdf"), {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
             var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
             var doc = new jsPDF({ unit: 'px', format: 'a4' });
             doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
             doc.save('NOME-DO-PDF.pdf');
             //Retorna ao CSS normal
             $("#gerapdf").width(cache_width);
         }
     });
 }
```

Por algum motivo, o gráfico não é gerado:

[image: PDF gerado sem o Gráfico]

Não conheço muito javascript/html. Alguem pode me orientar como proceder?
Já procurei bastante coisa, tentei várias, mas ainda sim não consegui.

Obrigado

Comment: O que você está usando para passar o Canvas para o PDF?

Comment: O html2canvas.js

Comment: [Parece que esse erro é famoso](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/95).